# vimdiff is not working under cywin with mobaxterm (E97 cannot create diffs)

Tags: vim, cygwin

On my PC I am using mobaxterm and installed vim in its cygwin environment.

vim and gvim works fine with no issue.

Only vimdiff is not working as I get the error : "E97: Cannot create diffs"

- I installed diffutils "GNU collection of diff" and checked it on 2
  files and it works fine.
- I have no disk full.
- I run vim -d or vimdiff without using my .vimrc and it is the same.
  So it is not coming from my vim configuration.
- I am using last version of mobaxterm (10.4) and vim v8 but the issue
  was the same with previous version (mobaxterm v9 and vim v7.X).
- I run vimdiff with -V option and I get :

  Calling shell to execute: "diff -a /tmp/vkjIw1o/0 /tmp/vkjIw1o/1 > /tmp/vkjIw1o/2"
                                  /tmp/vkjIw1o/0 /tmp/vkjIw1o/1 > /tmp/vkjIw1o/2"

  E97: Cannot create diffs

I can see that /tmp/vkjIw1o is created, no file inside.

This is same case as this very old post https://superuser.com/questions/455210/vimdiff-in-cygwin-is-not-working-properly .

It is annoying I still have this issue.
I hope someone solved this.

JP

---

More infos :

1) I modified one file (vimrc2). Running this command from vim works fine : :!diff ~/.vimrc ~/vimrc2

```
@@ -51,7 +51,7 @@
 "
 set showmode
 set ruler
-set cursorline
+"set cursorline
 set number
```

2) For temp dir, echo tempname() gives me /tmp/vmtID5W/1
Then I can save a file to /tmp with :w /tmp/test.txt

---

I solved the issue by adding this code in my .virmc file :

```
set diffexpr=MyDiff()
function MyDiff()
  let opt = ""
  if &diffopt =~ "icase"
    let opt = opt . "-i "
  endif
  if &diffopt =~ "iwhite"
    let opt = opt . "-b "
  endif
  silent execute "!/bin/diff.exe -a --binary " . opt . v:fname_in . " " . v:fname_new . " > " . v:fname_out
endfunction
```

I took the idea from https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1466
Note that I had to write `/bin/diff.exe`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: vimdiff works fine under mintty and under windows console.

Comment: Does :diffthis command work well? If not, check if your vim can access an external diff command and your temporary directory is readable and writable.

Comment: Your diff output looks something like an unified format but vim expects a normal one. Please check to see 'help diff'.

Comment: I appears that `diff` needs `-e` to output in ed format. I have not found yet how to tell vim to use the option. I found a `diffexpr` function here https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1466 but at present time I have not succeeded to make it work... Still investigating.

Comment: The normal format is diff's default, no need any option (--normal just in case ). Your diff might be different from the standard, right? And even if you would use diffexpr, the normal format is expected in v:fname_out file as an output.

Comment: ` diff --help
Usage: /bin/diff [OPTION]... FILES
Compare FILES line by line.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
      --normal                  output a normal diff (the default)
...
  -e, --ed                      output an ed script`

Comment: Oups, I thought I read somewhere that vim was expecting an ed format. In fact I misundersood.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem in MobaXTerm for a long time up to version 11.1. The reason (and solution) I finally found is twofold:

1. `E810` is about Vim being unable to write and read temporary files. If you run fugitive you get `E484` about the same.
2. `E97` is about wrong output of the `diff` executable called by Vim.

## Resolving `E810` and `E484`

In my case it was about wrong `set shellxquote=\"`, which I got during my searching for a solution. That setting is responsible for how Vim quotes filenames. Removing it, resulting in unsetting, resolved the error with writing and reading temporary files.

## Resolving `E97`

This is where the `diffexpr` comes to help. But it might not be sufficient itself. In my case I had to install `diffutils` package too as the `/bin/diff` was pointing to `busybox`, which supports *only* the unified diff format, while Vim requires ed-style (i.e. normal) diff format.

Now my diff executables are:

```bsh
lrwxrwxrwx     16 Jan 29 13:26 /bin/diff -> /bin/busybox.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 201.5K Dec  6  2016 /bin/diff.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x  56.0K Dec  6  2016 /bin/diff3.exe*
```

The difference in output is:

```bsh
$ /bin/diff one two
--- one
+++ two
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 no change
-file one
+file two
 no change

$ /bin/diff.exe one two
2c2
< file one
---
> file two
```

All that needs to be done is to point to the proper one in the `diffexpr` function:

```bsh
silent execute "!/bin/diff.exe  " . opt . v:fname_in . " " . v:fname_new . " > " . v:fname_out
```

Even the `-a --binary` options are not required.